# How to get only url results in SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql

I'm creating a new query in `sparql`.

I want to get those results that support link or url format.

My sample query:

```py
select DISTINCT ?p ?o where {

    <http://fkg.iust.ac.ir/resource/اهواز> ?p ?o
}
```

And my result:

[image: sample result]

I expected that `object` column includes only url fomat.

Comment: `filter(isIRI(?o))` you mean? See [SPARQL specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isIRI)

Comment: yeah that's right, thanks for helping @AKSW